# Setting a User's Valid Until date in the future

Tags: amazon-redshift

I was trying to see if there was a way to automatically set a user's VALID UNTIL value three months in the future without having to type out the literal date. Tried the following:

```
alter user rchung set valuntil = dateadd(day,90,GETDATE());
alter user rchung set valuntil = select dateadd(day,90,GETDATE());
```

both failed with a syntax error.

```
alter user rchung valid until dateadd(day,90,GETDATE());
```

also failed with a syntax error.

Anyone have any success with this?

TIA,
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a limitation on the PostgreSQL side.

> CREATE USER, like pretty much all utility statements in Postgres,
>   won't do any expression evaluation --- the parameters have to be
>   simple literal constants.

[VALID UNTIL programmatically in SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10495.1055338325%40sss.pgh.pa.us)

Since Amazon Redshift doesn't support plpgsql like PostgreSQL, client side scripting is really the only option. If you're using a semi-modern version (9.3+) of psql the following works:

```
select dateadd(day,90,GETDATE()) as expiry; \gset
alter user myuser valid until :'expiry';
```

Comment: I was worried that would be the case.  Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "day" does not exist